# Nested form not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I have three nested forms in my _form; ingredients, instructions, and nutrition. The first two work fine, but nutrition won't show any of the forms. If I rename "nutrition" to something else in the view the forms show, but since it is the wrong name the params don't get send correctly so nothing works. I have a feeling it is something small that I am overlooking, but would like to get anyones input.

**recipe.rb** relevant bits

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base


  has_many :ingredients, dependent: :destroy
  validates :ingredients, presence: true

  has_many :instructions, dependent: :destroy
  validates :instructions, presence: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :instructions, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

  has_one :nutrition, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :nutrition

end
```

**nutrition.rb**

```
class Nutrition < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
end
```

**ingredient.rb** for comparison to nutrition.rb

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe

  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Relevant parts of **recipes_controller.rb**

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController

  # GET /recipes/new
  def new
    @recipe = Recipe.new
  end

  # POST /recipes
  def create
    @recipe = current_user.recipes.new(recipe_params)

    if @recipe.save
      @recipe.upvote_by current_user
      redirect_to @recipe, notice: 'Recipe was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /recipes/1
  def update
    if @recipe.update(recipe_params)
      redirect_to @recipe, notice: 'Recipe was successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private
    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def recipe_params
      params.require(:recipe).permit(:name, :description, :image, :url, :category_id, ingredients_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy], instructions_attributes: [:id, :body, :image, :_destroy], nutrition_attributes: [:id, :serves, :serving_size, :calories, :fat, :carbs, :fiber, :protein])
    end
end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @recipe, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
```

```
    <h3>Nutrition</h3>
  <div class="nutrition">
    <%= f.fields_for :nutrition do |n| %>
<%# if I rename :nutrition to anything else the fields show, it seems to not enter this at all with :nutrition %>
      <%= render 'nutrition_fields', f: n %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <h3>Ingredients</h3>
  <div class="ingredients">
    <%= f.fields_for :ingredients do |ingredient| %>
      <%= render 'ingredient_fields', f: ingredient %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="links">
      <%= link_to_add_association 'add ingredient', f, :ingredients  %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <h3>Instructions</h3>
  <div class="instructions">
    <%= f.fields_for :instructions do |instruction| %>
      <%= render 'instruction_fields', f: instruction %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="links">
      <%= link_to_add_association 'add step', f, :instructions  %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**_nutrition_fields.html.erb**

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Serves" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :serves %>
  </div>

    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Serving Size" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :serving_size %>
  </div>

    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Calories" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :calories %>
  </div>

    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Fat" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :fat %>
  </div>

    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Total Carbohydrates" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :carbs %>
  </div>

    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Fiber" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :fiber %>
  </div>

    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Protein" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :protein %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What about `f.fields_for f.object.build_nutrition do |n|`?

Comment: @MrYoshiji Now the fields are showing with values of zero, but if I submit it doesn't send the params as "nutrition_attributes", it is just "nutrition"

Comment: That's weird. So using `f.fields_for :nutrition do |n|` makes the nutrition fields disappear?

Comment: same if you use a string instead of a symbol? (`f.fields_for 'nutrition'`) ; Can you try this also: `f.fields_for :nutrition_attributes`?

Comment: If I put a string it acts the same as with a symbol. If I put `:nutrition_attributes` the fields show but it doesn't save to the database. I added `@nutrition = Nutrition.new` to the new function in **recipe.rb** and now it seems to be working. I just noticed that the only reason the other two work is due to the `link_to_add_association` which creates the field with javascript, it doesn't show up by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController

 # GET /recipes/new
 def new
   @recipe = Recipe.new
   @nutrition = @recipe.build_nutrition
 end
```

Fields for:

```
<%= f.fields_for :nutrition, @nutrition do |n| %>
```

You have to build the association in the controller for a has_one fields_for to appear by default.

Comment: This works. Also it seems that you don't need to set `@nutrition` equal to anything, you can just call `@recipe.build_nutrition` and it works fine.

Comment: FYI `f.object` returns the object beeing filled in the form, in your case `f.object` is equal to `@recipe`